# How can I work with any assembly version

Tags: c#, assemblies

My application references an assembly that increases in version a lot.

I can set "Specific Version" in my Visual Studio reference to `false` so that I don't encounter any build issues but I need to be able to work with any version at runtime.

As far as I can see I have two options:

1. Request that the publisher of the dll uses a Publisher Policy File and adopts [Assembly Binding Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
2. Dynamically load the assembly using `Reflection`.

Now, with option 1, there is a chance that the assembly supplier can not be persuaded to use this technique.  I am pre-empting this as the supplier would have quite a lot of large redirects in their config due to the number of releases of this assembly.

With option 2, I would prefer not to use Reflection in this instance as I want to maintain the flexibility and ease that VS Intellisense brings.

So, my question is:  Is there a 3rd option or are my concerns about the first two options of no real significance?

Comment: Is the assembly a third-party library that you're using to build your application, or is it a plug-in to your application?

Comment: It's a piece of middleware between my application and a number of others.  We developed it but it's always being modified and has multiple source branches, existing in multiple test environments - hence the need to be able to deploy against any version.

Comment: Treating it as a third-party dependency, what causes a problem? What error are you receiving?

Comment: It's a "Cannot load assembly" manifest definition error, if it's in an application folder with a different version to the one against which it was compiled.

Comment: Does the assembly you're referencing have a strong name? Is the assembly version or file version being updated between builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2a: Use reflection to load it in release builds only. Override the AssemblyResolve event and load the assembly manually if it fails due to a versioning conflict.

Option 3: Don't change the version number. (Put it in a different field in the assembly info if you want a build number so you can tell different builds apart, but if the exposed API doesn't change, don't consider it to be a new version)

Comment: Thanks, I went with 2a.  It is simple, elegant and solves all my concerns.